# Inserting an element into an array in sorted order

Tags: java, arrays, insert

I'm trying to add an element into an array in sorted order.

This is my code :

```
public class SortedInsertion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr=new int[6];
        arr[0]=5;
        arr[1]=6;
        arr[2]=9;
        arr[3]=11;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        insert(7,arr);


    }

    public static void insert(int val,int[] arr){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){

            if(arr[i]>val)
                break;
        }
        for(int k=i;k<arr.length-1;k++){
            arr[k+1]=arr[k];
            arr[i]=val;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));


    }

}
```

I'm getting the output as:
[5, 6, 9, 11, 0, 0]

[5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9]

But the right out put is

5,6,9,11,0,0

5,6,7,9,11,0

Comment: `arr[k+1]=arr[k];     arr[i]=val` are executed several times (for loop). Hence the output.

Comment: Just use `System.arraycopy` to move the tail and make space. It's faster and clearer.

Comment: Solution inspired by [Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider) [with `System.arraycopy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135900/inserting-an-element-into-an-array-in-sorted-order/58471546#58471546)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `insert` method like this:

```
    public static void insert(int val,int[] arr){
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        if(arr[i]>val)
          break;
      }
      for(int k=arr.length-2; k>=i; k--){
        arr[k+1]=arr[k];            
      }
      arr[i]=val;
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    }
```

Comment: This takes o(n) order time. Can anyone write a better algorithm?

Comment: In particular, it does not work for values greater than 10: **[5, 6, 9, 11, 0, 11]**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Arrays or Collections binarySearch function to get the position to insert the new value at, you will need to shift all elements from this position (if any) to the right

`int position =    Math.abs(Collections.binarySearch(sortedList, key)) - 1;`

Answer (score 1):

There is an issues in your `for` loop

```
for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){}
```

It should iterate up to `i<arr.length`

```
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class InsertInSortedArray {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int arr[] = {5, 6, 9, 11};
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            int k = 7;
            int index = findIndexToBeInserted(arr, k, 0, arr.length - 1);
            ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i : arr)
                al.add(i);

            al.add(index, k);
            for (int i : al)
                System.out.println(i);
        }

    private static int findIndexToBeInserted(int[] arr, int k, int start, int end) {
            if (k == 0)
                return 0;

            int mid = (start + end) / 2;

            if (k > arr[mid] && k < arr[mid + 1])
                return mid + 1;

            if (arr[mid] < k)
                return findIndexToBeInserted(arr, k, mid + 1, end);

            return findIndexToBeInserted(arr, k, start, mid - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanations to your code: what programming language used, what benefits are there.

Comment: You don't know the `Arrays.binarySearch()`-function, don't You?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
arr[k+1]=arr[k];
```

You're overriding every next array element with a previous value. You should probably reverse your loop and move from the end of the array, shifting all elements forward until you find the right spot, i.e.:

```
public static void insert(int val, int[] arr) {
    for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) continue; // skip last elements to avoid array index out of bound
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];       // shift elements forward
        if (arr[i] <= val) {       // if we found the right spot
            arr[i] = val;          // place the new element and
            break;                 // break out the loop
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: for(int k=arr.length-1;k>i;k--){
   arr[k]=arr[k-1];

Comment: You tried to insert 12 with Your solution? Hint: **[5, 6, 9, 12, 11, 0]**

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving is by using List and collections.sort method.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  list.add(arr[i]); 
  } 
  list.add(val);

  Collections.sort(list);

 int[] result = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Hope this solutions helps.

Answer (score 0):

Java Code,

```
public static void insertElementInSortedArr(int a[], int val) {

        int n[] = new int[a.length + 1];
        int j = 0;
        boolean isAdded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] < val) {
                n[j] = a[i];
                j++;
            } else {
                if (!isAdded) {
                    n[j] = val;
                    j = j + 1;
                    isAdded = true;
                }
                n[j] = a[i];
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the array in question is not really sorted like this: `[0, 0, 5, 6, 9, 11]`.
It is a "zero tailed" array: `[5, 6, 9, 11, 0, 0]`.
So to insert a value into that array it needs to know how many elements occupied are. In case when you provide this value into a method it would have O(log n) complexity. Otherwise, it needs to implement counting inside the inserting method.

```
/**
* @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when the array is full and the value to be inserted is greater than the last element
*/
private static void insertToZeroTailedArray(int val, int[] arr) {
    // an O(n) operation to count occupied elements
    int elementsCount = 0;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            elementsCount = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // binarySearch returns a negative position to insert if the value was not found
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 0, elementsCount, val);
    if (index != 0) {
        int pos = index < 0
                ? -index - 1 // val not found, it is need to be inserted at (-index)-1 position
                : index;     // val found but we are going to insert it again

        // shift the array to right and drop last element because of the array bounds
        System.arraycopy(arr, pos, arr, pos + 1, arr.length - pos - 1);
        arr[pos] = val;
    } else {
        // the case when value is found at 0 position
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length - 1);
        arr[0] = val;
    }
}
```

An alternative way to do what you need with O(log n) complexity for **a really sorted array**:

```
private static void insertToReallySortedArray(int val, int[] arr) {
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, val);
    if (index != 0) {
        int pos = index < 0 ? -index - 1 : index;
        System.arraycopy(arr, pos, arr, pos + 1, arr.length - pos - 1);
        arr[pos] = val;
    } else {
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length - 1);
        arr[0] = val;
    }
}
```

Based on this great [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/binary-search-for-inserting-in-array#answer-36239).

Comment: _two flaws:_ an already existing value is not inserted and the solution busts with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for values greater 9…

Answer (score 0):

*completely unclear how an insert function should work without knowing the number of fields already occupied?*

```
public static void insert( int n, int occupied, int[] array ) {
  if( n >= array[occupied - 1] )
    array[occupied] = n;
  else
    for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
      int n1 = array[i];
      int n2 = array[i + 1];
      if( n1 > n || n1 < n && n2 >= n ) {
        if( n1 > n ) i--;
        System.arraycopy( array, i + 1, array, i + 2, occupied - i - 1 );
        array[i + 1] = n;
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

called from Your example above:

```
…
arr[3]=11;
int occupied = 4;
insert( 7, occupied, arr );  // [5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 0]
```

unchecked bust with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `occupied >= array.length`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the arrays.sort() functionality to insert a value into a new array then sort it. It solves the issue in a roundabout way. For example

```
    int num = 10;
    int array[] = {6, 7, 8};
    int copy_array[] = new int[array.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        copy_array[i] = array[i];
    }
    copy_array[copy_array.length - 1] = given_number;
    Arrays.sort(copy_array);
```