# Java Inserting numbers into an array in order

Tags: java, computer-science

I am having problems with an assignment.  I'm fairly new to coding and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this.  My professor supplied code for adding and removing items from an array but he wants us to add a method that would add items to the array in the correct position. This is the supplied code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayList {
private Object[]buffer;
private int currentSize;

public MyArrayList(){
   final int INITIAL_SIZE=10;
  buffer = new Object[INITIAL_SIZE];
  currentSize=0;
  }

public int size() {
  return currentSize;
  }

private void checkBounds(int n){
  if (n<0||n>= currentSize){
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
     }
  }
public Object get (int pos){
  checkBounds(pos);
  return buffer[pos];
  }
public Object remove(int pos){
  checkBounds(pos);
  Object removed = buffer[pos];
  for (int i = pos+1; i < currentSize; i++){
     buffer[i-1] = buffer[i];
  }
  currentSize--;
  return removed;
}
public boolean add(int pos, Object newElement){
  growBufferIfNecessary();
  currentSize++;
  checkBounds(pos);
  for(int i = currentSize - 1; i > pos; i--){
     buffer[i] = buffer [i-1];
  }
  buffer[pos] = newElement;
  return true;
}
public boolean addLast(Object newElement){
  growBufferIfNecessary();
  currentSize++;
  buffer[currentSize -1] = newElement;
  return true;
}
 private void growBufferIfNecessary(){
  if (currentSize==buffer.length){
     Object[] newBuffer = new Object[2*buffer.length];
     for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++){
     newBuffer[i] = buffer[i];
     }
  buffer = newBuffer;
   }
} 

}
```

This is our assignment:

Add a method called "public void insert(int n)" that will add n to your MyArrayList object  in the correct position maintaining the sorted order. Use your existing MyArrayList class with necessary modification.Here is a test case:

MyArrayList list = new MyArrayLst();

list.insert(5); insert(10); insert(8); insert(20); insert(6);

If you print the list now, it should print as:

5

6

8

10

20

So this is what I have so far in my main method:

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class ArrayListHomework {
 public static void main (String[]args){
 MyArrayList list = new MyArrayList();

 list.insert(5);
 list.insert(10);
 list.insert(8);
 list.insert(20);
 list.insert(6);
 for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){

     System.out.println(list.get(i));

   }
  }  
 }
```

I am super lost as to how to start this insert method.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Yo compare each element with element you are about to insert and find appropriate index and then insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting an element into an array in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135900/inserting-an-element-into-an-array-in-sorted-order)

Comment: You should start with a pen and paper and think about how would you perform the task of inserting a number into a specific position of a given list. When you have the theoretical stuff done, then you can start about the implementation

Comment: The given code is problematic in several ways, but a "high-level" pointer that is relevant here is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/binary-search-for-inserting-in-array#answer-36239

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions.  I got it to work by using the code that Marco13 suggested: 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/binary-search-for-inserting-in-array#answer-36239
Hope everyone has a great day and happy programming.
-TJ

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, and inexcusably, the code provided by your “professor” has a bug in the `add()` method, here:

```
public boolean add(int pos, Object newElement){
    growBufferIfNecessary();
    currentSize++;
    checkBounds(pos);
    // rest of method
```

Because `checkBounds()` is not called first, if `pos` is out of bounds, `currentSize` will be incremented (and the buffer unnecessarily grown), putting the instance in an inconsistent/erroneous state.

> Coding 101: First, check parameters.

To fix:

```
public boolean add(int pos, Object newElement){
    checkBounds(pos);
    growBufferIfNecessary();
    currentSize++;
    // rest of method
```

To answer your question, you must implement what’s called an [*insertion sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). Briefly, this means use a loop to iterate over all elements, and insert the new element at the point you encounter a larger element, or reach the end of the elements.

Note that if your array elements are not already sorted, calling `insert()` is meaningless. To handle this case, you should consider throwing an `IllegalStateException` if elements are out of order (you can check as you iterate that the previous element is not greater than the current element as you iterate).

Answer (score 1):

*not exactly like insertion sort, because there are free spaces with null-values*

```
public void insert( int n ) {
  growBufferIfNecessary();
  for( int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++ ) {
    if( buffer[i] == null ) {
      buffer[i] = n; currentSize++;
      break;
    }
    else if( buffer[i + 1] != null ) {
      int n1 = ((Number)buffer[i]).intValue();
      int n2 = ((Number)buffer[i + 1]).intValue();
      if( n1 < n && n2 > n ) {
        System.arraycopy( buffer, i + 1, buffer, i + 2, currentSize - i - 1 );  // line 1
        buffer[i + 1] = n; currentSize++;  // line 2
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `add()` function could substitute  line 1   and   line 2